# qgis2web: pop up options inside grouped layers

Tags: openlayers, qgis2web

I have a rather complex QGIS project that I wanted to publish using the qgis2web plugin. I aim to maintain the layer tree structure with layers grouped, and I would also like to have pop-ups in my web map project. However, I am experiencing issues in obtaining the pop-up options for the grouped layers. I can set the pop-ups only for the ungrouped layers (as shown in the picture below). Is there some kind of workaround for this, or could I receive any pointers on how to manage this manually within the code generated by the plugin?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groups are not supported in qgis2web.
For OpenLayers export, the only way is to export the project and then edit the `layers.js` file as per this example

```js
    var layersList = [
    new ol.layer.Group({
                title: 'Basemap',
                layers: [
    lyr_GoogleLabels_0,lyr_GoogleTerrain_1,lyr_GoogleSatellite_2,lyr_OpenStreetMap_3,lyr_SfondoBianco_4,
    ]}),
    new ol.layer.Group({
                title: 'WMS Catasto',
                fold: 'close',
                layers: [
    lyr_WMSCatastoFogli_5,lyr_WMSCatastoStrade_6,lyr_WMSCatastoAcque_7,lyr_WMSCatastoParticellezoom200m_8,lyr_WMSCatastoFabbricatizoom200m_9,lyr_WMSCatastoVestizionizoom100m_10,
    ]}),
    new ol.layer.Group({
                title: 'Vincoli e Tutele',
                fold: 'open',
                layers: [
    lyr_PaiEsondazioniagg2016_11,lyr_PaiFraneagg2016_12,lyr_ParchieRiserve_14,lyr_VincoloIdrogeologico_15,lyr_VincoliArcheologiciArt142m_17,lyr_GalassiniDM310785_18,lyr_BellezzeNaturaliArt136_19,lyr_ZPS_20,lyr_SIC_21,
    ]}),
    new ol.layer.Group({
                title: 'Cartografia generale',
                fold: 'open',
                layers: [
    lyr_ToponimiMonti_13,lyr_ReticoloIdrografico_16,lyr_ConfiniComunali_22,lyr_ConfiniProvinciali_23
    ]}),
    ];
```

Comment: Hi @andreaordonselli, thanks for your prompt reply, so I've tried to change code in Layers.js so now these layers are within this list, sadly now web map won't generate. Should I remove LayerList below the altered code (it was already there)?

Comment: in the qgis project deletes all layer groups.  layers must not be positioned inside a group but outside.  export with qgis2web then in the layers.js file edit "var layersList" as in my example, creating the ol.layer.Groups you want.  write your lyr_xxx inside each specific group.

Comment: Okay, so what I ended up with is this: I edited the code as you suggested, but sadly, no pop-ups appeared on the web map. Therefore, I ungrouped the layers that were most crucial for me to have the pop-ups. So, it's something in between.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to tell you that if you group the layers the popup on hover and higlight on hover functionality will no longer work. The solution is here: https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/1011

Comment: I've actually saw that issue with your solution, but I am not really sure what needs to be changed exactly within these functions that you are mentioning. Sorry, but I am a bit of a OpenLayers newby and don't know how things works around here.